# Angular material tabs - change tabs on hover

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there an effective way to invoke the tab change on hover as well as on-click?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat hacky, but I've don't find any other solution, here is a working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tabs-material-8revug?file=app%2Ftabs-overview-example.ts).

Another important thing, you should detached those tab listeners `OnDestroy`.

```
ngOnInit() {

  let checkExist = setInterval(() => { 
    // grab the tabs
    let tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.mat-tab-label');

    //if all the tabs rendered
    if (tabs?.length == this.tabs?.length) {

      //run and attach mouseenter listeners
      for(let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
        tabs[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', ()=>{

          //when mouse entering tab - trigger click on it
          tabs[i].click();
        });
      }
      //after listener attached - clear the interval
      clearInterval(checkExist);
    }
  }, 100);  

}
```